# Revert buffer with coding system

Tags: utf-8, revert-buffer

Chances  are that every time utf-coding should be activated by invoking 'M-x revert-coding-system` , even though a long list of utf-prefer configuration:

```
(prefer-coding-system        'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system  'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system  'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq locale-coding-system   'utf-8)
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Try to automate the process by

```
;;Set buffer coding system
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (revert-buffer-with-coding-system  "utf-8")))
```

However, it does not work as expected.

What's the problem with my function to to handle the `revert-buffer-with-coding-system'`

Comment: 1. Calling `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` in the major mode hook looks wrong. The selection of the major mode (`set-auto-mode` in `normal-mode` in `after-find-file`) is part of `revert-buffer`. 2. Why do you want to call `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` in the first place? Does the auto-selection of the coding system go wrong such that characters are shown in wrong encoding?

Comment: Yes, it failed to display Chinese characters. @Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already tried to describe in my comment:
`(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (revert-buffer-with-coding-system  "utf-8")))`
cannot work because `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` *indirectly runs* `org-mode-hook`. So you get into an infinite loop.

Thereby, *"indirectly runs"* means:

- the major mode hook `org-mode-hook` is run by the major mode function `org-mode`
- the major mode function is run by `set-auto-mode-0` with is part of `set-auto-mode`
- `set-auto-mode` is run by `normal-mode`
- `normal-mode` is run by `revert-buffer` (which is the essential part of `revert-buffer-with-coding-system`)

---

You can enforce the coding system for reading `.org` files with the following line in your init file:

```el
(add-to-list 'file-coding-system-alist '("\\.org\\'" . utf-8))
```